# Google Optimize w/ FIrst-Party Cookie Not Working

Tags: optimization, cookies, google-optimize

I'm trying to set up a Google Optimize experiment off a First-Party Cookie to serve different content to logged in users vs new users.
The cookie name I'm evaluating is: intercom-session-xxxx
When a new user comes to the page, the "Content" value for "intercom-session-xxxx" is empty. Once a user is logged in, there is a unique ID associated to the value.
I set up the experiment in two ways, both of which were unsuccessful.
1. intercom-session-xxxx CONTAINS "a" or "b" or "c"...(all the way through all letters [lowercase and capital] and numbers 0-9)
2. intercom-session-xxxx DOES NOT CONTAIN "not set"

Both methods triggered the experiment when I first visited the page via Icognito, and I verified that the Content of intercom-session-xxxx was empty (a false positive in both cases). And then the experiment continued to be true once I logged in and the Content was actually populated.

Has anyone had any success running experiments off of whether a cookie has Content or not? I'm probably doing something stupid, so any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: update: I've also tried keying off of a Javascript variable that is just being set to true/false if the cookie has Content. Console is tracking true/false results properly, but again, Optimize is not triggering the experiment when var "loggedIn" = true (despite that being the exact criteria set).

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue with unique cookie values for logged in users.

Have you tried creating a new first party cookie that triggers under the same conditions? That way you can control the value (eg, to something like "true") and use that to target. I was easily able to create a new first party cookie to attach to logged-in users via Google Tag Manager.

I also tried to used regex, with the criteria being set to:
.*
This didn't work - it simply targeted ALL users to site, not just those with the cookie set.

Answer (score -1):

I'm also having this issue. Changing the regex to '.+' didn't rectify the issue so it looks like an Optimize bug.